# Doxygen: Seamless documentation for project with C++ and VHDL

Tags: c++, doxygen, vhdl

I'm setting up a documentation about some sort of Library which consists of a C/C++ part and a VHDL part, plus some instructive doxygen-only pages. They have to be put into one self-contained group. Everything works so far, nice and fluffy...

But what if I want to optimize the output in the vhdl-subdirectory by using `OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL = YES` and optimize the output of the c-subdirectory by using `OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_C = YES` at the same time?

As far as I understand, using [doxygen-tags](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/external.html) is not optimal in my case, since it introduces new doxyfile.conf-files in each subdirectory, with independent runs of doxygen in each subdirectory. So, doing this I can't put both parts (c+vhdl) in different subgroups of the same group anymore, and links between the two parts are not possible. Also, the whole module should be "selfcontained", to be includable into bigger documentations, without the special build-structure involved in this solution...

What would you do?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - eventually what we did is:

1. Create a different directory for C code and VHDL code (+ respective doxygen comment files - as we didn't want to spam the code with doxygen tags everywhere).
2. Run Doxygen for each of these directories (each with it's own oprimization tag - `OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL`  or `OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_C` )
3. Combine (manually!!!- though you can create a script for it) the output of these two directories such that the main page would reference the two directories.

Eventually I decided to shorten the time it takes to generate the documentation, and I just ignore the optimization tags...