# Mixed C and VHDL documentation in Doxygen

Tags: c, vhdl, documentation, doxygen

I have an embedded project that consists of a microcontroller (C) and an FPGA (VHDL), for that I wish to create a documenation.

The question ist similar to [Doxygen: Seamless documentation for project with C++ and VHDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102770/doxygen-seamless-documentation-for-project-with-c-and-vhdl)

But I don't have as strict requirements as there. That is, I don't need intermixing in the same group  or interlinking. I would simply like to have two modules: "VHDL" and "C", each optimized for respective language, but in the same documenation.

Perhaps someone has come up with a solution in the past 8 years?

Comment: In the cited question there is a possible solution given, disadvantage is a bit that one is mixed multiple styles. An approach might be similar, but for the secondary part create a TAG file and in the main part use this TAG file. I didn't try it, just a thought that came into my mind.

Comment: @albert I need more explanatation abou this TAG

Comment: Please have a a look in the documentation chapter about configuration and the chapter: Linking to external documentation. Here are you find the settings `GENERATE_TAGFILE` and `TAGFILES`